# How does Speed in Animator Window in Unity work?

Tags: unity, animation

If speed 1 is considered normal playback, is it by a second? So animation play once in a second? If I have my animator speed set as 100, would it make the speed become 0.06 then ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed value is a multiplier.

1 means 1 x animations speed. So if the animation was originally authored as 10 seconds long, it will play over the course of 10 seconds.

If you set the speed multiplier to 2, then you'll play back at double speed, and the 10-second-long animation will finish in 5 seconds.

If you set the speed multiplier to 0.5, then you'll play back at half speed, and the 10-second-long animation will finish in 20 seconds.

Setting the multiplier up to 100 would make the animation finish in a tenth of a second if it was originally 10 seconds long.